# How to customize HTML submit buttons?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, submit-button

How would I make a submit button appear as just plain text which will override the default browser button style?

I have searched the internet but all I find is how to put a image for a submit button.

Comment: Well of course but what would be the process to do this?

Comment: Look at [bootstrap `btn-link` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `background-color: transparent;` *(Or you can use `hex` as well)* and `border: 0;`, that will get you the desired result.

```
input[type="submit"].plain {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent; /* Or whatever background color you want to use */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U5vBV/)

Comment: Thanks for the simple and fast answer.

Comment: How would I make the curser turn into a hand indicating that it is active?

Comment: @HeyItsProdigy Use `cursor: pointer;` http://jsfiddle.net/U5vBV/2/ or if you want on active than use `:active` instead of `:hover`

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=submit] {
border:none;
background-color:white;
 }
```

And an example you can find here:

http://jsfiddle.net/f7x35/

Answer (score 0):

You could style it something like this, and then make the needed tweaks to it to make it fit the rest of your design.

```
input[type=submit]{
    border: 0px;
    background: inherit;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The `background: inherit;` is to make sure it follows your original background color.